# spring-data-mongodb: Method findAndReplace, findAndModify... and auditing

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a couple of questions about the method [findAndReplace](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.find-and-replace) of spring-data-mongodb:

- Is this operation really atomic?
- What is the reason for the methods
  findAndReplace, findAndModify... methods not trigger the auditing
  event?

  ```java
   @Autowired
  MongoOperations mongoOperations;
  ...
  public void persist() {

          final Query query = new Query();
          query.addCriteria(where("id").is(product.getId()));

          mongoOperations.findAndReplace(query, entity, new FindAndReplaceOptions().upsert().returnNew());
  ```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some code that illustrates your question.

Comment: @RoarS. Code added. Inject a MongoOperations and use method findAndReplace